# Forbid two columns to have the same name in MySQL resultset?

Tags: mysql, configuration

One can do a `SELECT` with two columns having the same name in MySQL, like

```
SELECT city.name, country.name FROM city 
INNER JOIN country ON (country.id = city.idCountry)
```

But is there a way to **have MySQL return an error/warning in such case** (two columns in a resultset having the same name)?

Because PHP (PDO or mysqli) doesn't care if two columns have the same name: it will simply consider the last one only. I would like to get yelled an error in such case, to avoid painful searches deep in code just to find that a query had two identical columns. Is there a MySQL option/variable for such thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a configuration parameter (although I doubt it).  A "hacky" way to do this would be to use a subquery:

```
select x.*
from (SELECT city.name, country.name
      FROM city INNER JOIN
           country
           ON country.id = city.idCountry
    ) x;
```

MySQL will return an error if a subquery has duplicate column names.

Comment: Nice hacky thing indeed, even if I won't really use it (because the total overcost or writing, reading, and never-forgetting this would be bigger than few digging when the bug occurs).

Comment: @Xenos . . . If you just wanted to test the query, you could put a `LIMIT 1` in the subquery.  Or, better yet, create a view.  It will also fail if the columns are the same -- but your query has to conform to the limitation of a MySQL view.